# Is there a codenameone class like java.awt.Polygon?

Tags: java, codenameone

Is there any class in codenameone that allows me to make a polygon from a set of coordinates and then test to see if a point is contained inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. [Shape](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/geom/Shape.html) is the base interface for such functionality and the equivalent for Polygon is [GeneralPath](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/geom/GeneralPath.html).

Comment: You should also mention the `contains` method